# How to validate a form using JSON Schema?

Tags: javascript, json, validation, jsonschema

I want to validate the input from an HTML form using a JSON Schema describing it. I'm using Gary Court's JSV to validate it and it returns an error consistently. I used JSON Schema Lint (jsonschemalint.com) to check my schema. In Chrome Schema Lint tells me my schema is valid, but in Firefox, Safari & Opera the website tells me that my schema is valid JSON but not valid JSON schema. Can anyone help me out. My schema is below.

**UPDATE 8/6/13** Thank you for all your replies. My updated JSON (updated below) is now validating in all browsers. However I am still getting the following error from JSV:

```
Report {errors: Array[1], validated: Object, instance: JSONInstance, schema: JSONSchema,   schemaSchema: JSONSchema…}
errors: Array[1]
    0: Object
        attribute: "type"
        details: Array[1]
            0: "object"
            length: 1
            __proto__: Array[0]
        message: "Instance is not a required type"
        schemaUri: "http://json-schema.org/draft-03/hyper-schema#"
        uri: "urn:uuid:808fe74b-b0d0-4774-8975-289f105dfeaa#"
        __proto__: Object
    length: 1
    __proto__: Array[0]
instance: JSONInstance
schema: JSONSchema
schemaSchema: JSONSchema
validated: Object
__proto__: Report
```

Let me first say that I may be interpreting the error message incorrectly. However I'm fairly certain this is referring to the `"type": "object"` line directly after the opening curly bracket. However the `"type": "object"` key:value is part of the Draft 03 spec at https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-zyp-json-schema-03. This is confusing because JSON Schema Lint uses the JSV library as well... Thanks for all your help so far.

```
{
"type": "object",
"$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-03/schema#",
"title": "FormValidation",
"description": "Describes the types of and valid inputs to a form generated via Form Creator",
"properties": {
    "Air Temperature (C)": {
        "type": "number",
        "description": "Air Temperature measurement in centigrade.",
        "required": false
    },
    "Ammonia": {
        "type": "number",
        "description": "Ammonia measurement at test site.",
        "required": false
    },
    "Aquatic Life Present": {
        "type": "string",
        "description": "Are organisms such as fish or frogs living near the test site?",
        "required": false
    },
    "Chlorophyll a": {
        "type": "number",
        "description": "Chlorophyll a measurement at test site.",
        "required": false
    },
    "Conductivity": {
        "type": "number",
        "description": "Water conductivity measurement at test site.",
        "required": false
    },
    "Date of Test": {
        "type": "string",
        "description": "Date the measurements were recorded.",
        "required": true
    },
    "Dissolved Oxygen 1": {
        "type": "number",
        "description": "Disolved oxygen reading at first depth.",
        "required": false
    },
    "Dissolved Oxygen 2": {
        "type": "number",
        "description": "Dissolved oxygen reading at second depth.",
        "required": false
    },
    "Latitude": {
        "type": "number",
        "description": "Latitude of the measurement site in degrees.",
        "required": true
    },
    "Longitude": {
        "type": "number",
        "description": "Longitude of the measurement site in degrees.",
        "required": true
    },
    "Nitrates": {
        "type": "number",
        "description": "Nitrate measurement at test site.",
        "required": false
    },
    "Orthophosphates": {
        "type": "number",
        "description": "Orthophosphate measurement at site of testing.",
        "required": false
    },
    "Phosphates": {
        "type": "number",
        "description": "Phosphate reading at measurement site.",
        "required": false
    },
    "Secchi Disk": {
        "type": "number",
        "description": "Secchi Disk depth reading at measurement site.",
        "required": false
    },
    "Site Change": {
        "type": "string",
        "description": "Has the site undergone noticeable physical change since the last measuring event?",
        "required": false
    },
    "Test Site": {
        "type": "string",
        "description": "Location where the measurements were recorded.",
        "required": true
    },
    "Turbidity (ntu)": {
        "type": "number",
        "description": "Cloudiness or haziness of water, measured in Nephelometric Turbidity Units (NTU).",
        "required": false
    },
    "Water Color or Odor": {
        "type": "string",
        "description": "Does the water have an strange colorations or emit a noticeable odor?",
        "required": false
    },
    "Water Temperature (C)": {
        "type": "number",
        "description": "Water Temperature measurement in centigrade.",
        "required": false
    },
    "pH": {
        "type": "number",
        "description": "pH measurement at test site.",
        "required": false
    }
}
}
```

Comment: could it be "required" can only be 'true' or 'false' near the beginning ? you've got it set to a number of non-boolean values.

Comment: Try this one also: http://jsonlint.com/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I checked it again in [the JSON schema website](http://jsonschema.net) and it seems the name `"Turbidity (ntu)"` is not a valid key. `JSON schema`does not 'like' parentheses in a key. It works if you leave the parentheses out, like in `"Turbidity ntu"`.

I was just commenting on @pmagunia's entry when he apparently withdrew it. He remarked that `required` can only contain boolean values.
It seems to me that the `required` property at the top is actually superfluous. I just tested it in [JSON Schema Lint](http://jsonschemalint.com/) and the schema is said to be valid without it. But `required` can definitely *only* hold boolean values. Your array

```
[ "TestSite", "Date of Test", "Latitude", "Longitude" ]
```

was transformed by JSON Schema Lint into an unquoted string

```
TestSite,Date of Test,Latitude,Longitude
```

which will definitely be invalid JSON!

Comment: No, that wasn't it. Just checked again. This time all the parentheses were accepted. Strange. Sorry ...

Comment: cars10 is correct; the array of required properties is only valid in the v4 draft of json-schema and should therefore be removed as you are using the v3 draft.

Answer (score 3):

Your json have whitespaces in keys. Like `Air Temperature (C)`. Also remove the parenthesis. If you will remove whitespaces from your keys then it would be valid schema.